# Question about Using r.mapcalculator in Python console

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

According to the following conversation:
[Using r.mapcalculator in Python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129639/using-r-mapcalculator-in-python-console)

I tried:

```
##NoData Background=name
##RASTERLAYER_BAND=raster
##nodatabackground=output raster

import processing

ext = RASTERLAYER_BAND.extent() 
a = str(ext.xMinimum()) 
b = str(ext.xMaximum()) 
c = str(ext.yMinimum()) 
d = str(ext.yMaximum()) 
size = a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d

nodatabackground=processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator', RASTERLAYER_BAND,None,None,None,None,None,'A/A*A',size,0.0,nodatabackground)
```

But it doesn't work to me. I get the following message: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'extent'

Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add something like

```
raster = processing.getObject(RASTERLAYER_BAND)
```

and remove

```
nodatabackground=processing.runalg(...)
```

---

The following works for me:

```
##NoData Background=name
##RASTERLAYER_BAND=raster
##nodatabackground=output raster

import processing

raster = processing.getObject(RASTERLAYER_BAND)
ext = raster.extent() 
a = str(ext.xMinimum()) 
b = str(ext.xMaximum()) 
c = str(ext.yMinimum()) 
d = str(ext.yMaximum()) 
size = a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d

processing.runalg('grass:r.mapcalculator', raster,None,None,None,None,None,'A/A*A',size,0.0,nodatabackground)
```

Comment: Yes. Indeed, it works like that also to me. Great!!

Comment: @Nico_77 - Brilliant, glad it worked ;)

Comment: The problem is solved with the solution provided by Joseph